# Read value from database, echo

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Very basic but as a rookie I am struggling. The echo doesnt show any value, just the text. What am I doing wrong?

Connect.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('test.com.mysql', 'test_com_systems', 'systems');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'swaut_com_systems');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

Get.php:

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');
        $query2 = "SELECT systemid FROM user WHERE username=test";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);

    echo ( 'SystemID: '.$result2);

    ?>
```

Comment: you have to **fetch** the results before you can use them. `$result2` is just a pointer to the collection of results. perhaps you should try reading some tutorials about `mysqli_`?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann ah, too late for me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have connected to the database successfully then the query is incorrect. You must wrap all text values in quotes like this

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');
    $query2 = "SELECT systemid FROM user WHERE username='test'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
```

Now the `mysqli_query` submits the query to the database where it is run and a result set built. To see the result set you need to read the result set back from the database using one of the `fetch` functions for example

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

    echo 'SystemID: ' . $row['systemid'];
```

If there are more than one rows in the result set you must do that in a loop like this

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        echo 'SystemID: ' . $row['systemid'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the `mysqli` result `object`. In order to `print`the result you have to use:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the results of the `mysqli_query` using the following:

```
require('connect.php');
$query2 = "SELECT systemid FROM user WHERE username=test";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);    

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
{
   echo "System ID is: " .  $row['systemid'];
}
```

Comment: OP is using the `mysqli_*` API, but your answer is using the `mysql_*` API

Comment: sorry, I was looking at another question at the same time and got the two mixed up.

Comment: Better fix your answer then